# What does the compound mean?

Tags: meaning, compounds

> Given the general inauthenticity of the names in the Atcs, ir is not
>   surprising that scholars should suggest that **the one authentic one
>   gets it right** not because of actual historical knowledge deriving
>   from thomas, but more likely by drawing on a pool of general knowledge
>   about india available in Syria, the most probable place of
>   composition. (Huxley, George L. 1983. Geography in the Acts of Thomas,
>   In “Greek, Roman and Byzantine Studies”, Duke University Press,
>   Durham.)

I understand the meaning of the sentence generally, but I do not understand meaning of the bolded section. Could somebody explain the compound to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, it is badly written.

"...one authentic one.." is mixing the use of "one" as a number and "one" as in "single person or thing."

So rewritten, it would probably be more like:

> Given the general inauthenticity of the names in the Atcs, it is not
>   surprising that scholars should suggest that the single authentic one
>   gets it right...

In other words, `one <adjective> one` is not some particular idiom or expression.  It is just mixing "one" the adjective with "one" the noun to bad effect.